# Why did this vercel.json file update break my app?

Tags: python, next.js, vercel, openai-api

So I updated my vercel.json file based on recommendation from Vercel support to properly set the maxDuration time of my function and now I am getting 404 errors. Any insight as to what I am overlooking would be greatly appreciated!

Before;

```
{

  "version": 2,

  "builds": [{ "src": "chat.py", "use": "@vercel/python" }],

  "routes": [{ "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "chat.py" }],

  "functions": {

    "chat.py": {

      "maxDuration": 200

    }

  }

}
```

After;

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/api/message",
      "dest": "/api/chat.py"
    }
  ],
  "functions": {
    "api/chat.py": {
      "maxDuration": 200
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Script itself;

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import os
import time
from openai import OpenAI

# Load environment variables
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)

# Assistant ID and Configuration
ASSISTANT_ID = "Must have TSSC"
RUN_STATUS_CHECK_INTERVAL = 0.5  # seconds
RUN_STATUS_MAX_ATTEMPTS = 600

# Initialize OpenAI client
client = OpenAI()

def handle_run_status(run, thread_id):
    for _ in range(RUN_STATUS_MAX_ATTEMPTS):
        run = client.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(
            thread_id=thread_id,
            run_id=run.id,
        )

        # Check the status of the run and return early if completed or failed
        if run.status == "completed":
            return run
        elif run.status == "failed":
            print(f"Run failed: {run.last_error}")
            return run
        elif run.status not in ["queued", "in_progress", "requires_action"]:
            print(f"Run ended with status: {run.status}")
            return run

        # Wait for a short interval before checking again
        time.sleep(RUN_STATUS_CHECK_INTERVAL)

    # If the run did not complete in the expected time, log the event and return the run object
    print("Run did not complete in expected time.")
    return run

def submit_message(assistant_id, thread_id, user_message):
    try:
        print(f"Submitting message to thread: {user_message}")
        client.beta.threads.messages.create(
            thread_id=thread_id, 
            role="user", 
            content=user_message
        )
        print("Creating run...")
        run = client.beta.threads.runs.create(
            thread_id=thread_id,
            assistant_id=assistant_id,
        )
        return run
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in submit_message: {e}")
        raise

def get_response(thread_id):
    try:
        # Retrieve messages, ensuring they are in ascending order
        response = client.beta.threads.messages.list(thread_id=thread_id, order="asc")
        print(f"Retrieved messages: {response}")  # Log the retrieved messages

        # Check if response is empty or not as expected
        if not response.data:
            raise ValueError("No data in response")

        # Retrieve the latest assistant response
        # Iterate in reverse to find the latest assistant message
        for msg in reversed(response.data):
            if msg.role == "assistant":
                for content in msg.content:
                    if content.type == 'text':
                        assistant_response = content.text.value
                        print('\nAssistant output: ' + str(assistant_response) + '\n')
                        return assistant_response

        # Raise an error if no assistant response is found
        raise ValueError("No assistant responses found")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in get_response: {e}")
        raise

@app.route('/message', methods=['POST'])
def chat():
    user_message = request.json.get('message')
    thread_id = request.json.get('thread_id', None)

    try:
        if not thread_id:
            print("Creating new thread...")
            thread = client.beta.threads.create()
            thread_id = thread.id
        else:
            print(f"Retrieving thread: {thread_id}")

        run = submit_message(ASSISTANT_ID, thread_id, user_message)
        run = handle_run_status(run, thread_id)

        if run.status == 'completed':
            assistant_response = get_response(thread_id)
        else:
            assistant_response = "Assistant did not respond in time or run failed."

        print("Sending response:", {'response': assistant_response, 'thread_id': thread_id})
        return jsonify({'response': assistant_response, 'thread_id': thread_id})

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in chat: {e}")
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Next.js Route Handler;

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    console.log("Received request:", request); // Log incoming request

    // Forward the request to the Python backend
    console.log("Forwarding request to backend");
    const backendRes = await fetch(
      "https://rooted-gpt-chat-script.vercel.app/api/message",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(await request.json()),
      }
    );

    console.log("Received response from backend"); // Log backend response

    if (!backendRes.ok) {
      console.error("Error from backend:", backendRes.status); // Log backend error
      throw new Error(`Error from backend: ${backendRes.status}`);
    }

    // Get the response from the backend
    const data = await backendRes.json();
    console.log("Backend data:", data); // Log the data from backend

    // Send the response back to the frontend
    return NextResponse.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Request failed:", error); // Log error
    return new NextResponse(
      JSON.stringify({ message: "Internal Server Error" }),
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}

export const runtime = "edge";
```

I have tried converting to a FastAPI application and faced the same issue.